# How to create dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make this dynamic form?

[image: mockup]Hello How to make this dynamic form?

"Possible answer" must have: name='1', name='2', name='3' to name='6'.

Comment: Please explain your question in detail

Answer (score 1):

You need a plugin like

- AWESOME FORMS
- JQWIZARD
- SMART WIZARD

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/wizard

> to convert a form into a multipage user experience with thumbnails for
>   easy navigation